# Can I use a MAX17262 to measure battery capacity of a 300mA 3.7V Lipo?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lipo, battery-chemistry, fuel-gauge

First, I a very basic understanding of lithium based batteries and from what I have learned, gauging their capacity can be quite complex. I was looking into [MAX17262](https://www.analog.com/en/products/max17262.html#product-overview) as a fuel gauge to measure the capacity of a 300mA 3.7V LiPo battery. Looking through the datasheet, it mentions lithium ions, but not lithium polymers explicitly. If the underlying chemistry is the same, would the capacity estimation method used by the MAX17262 for lithium ions apply to lipos as well? Therefore the underlying question is, can I use the MAX17262 to measure a LiPo?

Circuit details: I have MAX17262 in series with the Lipo positive terminal that is fed into a BMS IC with a buck converter. The MAX17262 is interfaced over I2C with an MCU.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx4zBB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lithium polymer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) is a *subcategory* of [lithium-ion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery).

In the datasheet, the `ModelCfg` register selects the type of battery chemistry being used. Specifically, using a `ModelID` value of 0 is meant for most lithium types (this would include both Li-ion and Li-po).

*(2 is for [Nickel Cobalt Aluminum Oxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_nickel_cobalt_aluminium_oxides) (NCA, NCR) types, while 6 is for [Lithium Iron Phosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate) (LiFePO<sub>4</sub>).)*

[image: Datasheet excerpt]

In short, yes, you should be able to use the MAX17262's coulomb counter (aka fuel gauge) to successfully measure lithium polymer cells.